# How to access "$this" from a function

Tags: php, model-view-controller, aop

I use an homemade MVC system, in which Views access the model by being within the context of a method, and therefore able to access `$this`.

Example of a view, included dynamically :

```
...
<div>
   Hello <?= $this->user->name ?>
</div>
...
```

Now, I have some code that I would like to factorize into functions, with some extra parameters.
For example :

```
function colored_hello($color) {
?>
<div style="background-color:<?= $color ?>">
   Hello <?= $this->user->name ?>
</div>
<?
}
```

The problem is that I do not have access to `$this`, since the function is not a method. 
But I do not want to spoil my model or controller with presentation stuff.

Hance, I would like to be able to call this function dynamically, as a method. 
Like aspect oriented programming :

```
# In the top view
magic_method_caller("colored_hello", $this, "blue")
```

Is it possible ?
Or do you see a better way of doing it ?

Comment: why don't you pass $this as an argument? Also, have a look on `call_user_func` in the php manual.

Comment: *Views access the model* - oh my…

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Closure::bindTo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php)

You'll have to define/call your functions slightly differently, but you will be able to access `$this` from inside your object.

```
class test {
    private $property = 'hello!';
}

$obj = new test;

$closure = function() {
    print $this->property;
};

$closure = $closure->bindTo($obj, 'test');

$closure();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$this` as a property, but in all seriousness: you shouldn't really have functions in your view files.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit a hack but you can use debug_backtrace() to get the callers object. But I think you can only public values:

```
function colored_hello($color) {
  $tmp=debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT);
  $last=array_pop($tmp);

  $caller = $last['object'];

  print_r($tmp);
  print_r($last);
  print_r($caller);

  ?>
  <div style="background-color:<?= $color ?>">
     Hello <?= $caller->user->name ?>
  </div>
  <?
}
```

(code is not testet but it gives you a hint :-) )

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively pass it into the function:

```
function coloured_hello($object, $color) {
     //Code
     $object->user->name;
}
```

Comment: or use Class Type Hints - cause it's dedicated for this purposes